# Scala Comprehension Errors

Tags: string, scala, yield, for-comprehension

I am working on some of the exercism.io exercises.  The current one I am working on is for Scala DNA exercise.  Here is my code and the errors that I am receiving:

For reference, DNA is instantiated with a strand String.  This DNA can call count (which counts the strand for the single nucleotide passed) and nucletideCounts which counts all of the respective occurrences of each nucleotide in the strand and returns a `Map[Char,Int]`.

```
class DNA(strand:String) {

  def count(nucleotide:Char): Int = {
    strand.count(_ == nucleotide)
  }

  def nucleotideCounts = (
    for {
      n <- strand
      c <- count(n)
    } yield (n, c)
  ).toMap

}
```

The errors I am receiving are:

> Error:(10, 17) value map is not a member of Int
>         c <- count(n)
>                   ^
>
> Error:(12, 5) Cannot prove that Char <:< (T, U).   ).toMap
>       ^
>
> Error:(12, 5) not enough arguments for method toMap: (implicit ev:
>   <:<[Char,(T, U)])scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U]. Unspecified
>   value parameter ev.   ).toMap
>       ^

I am quite new to Scala, so any enlightenment on why these errors are occurring and suggestions to fixing them would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` comprehensions work over Traversable's that have `flatMap` and `map` methods defined, as the error message is pointing out.

In your case `count` returns with a simple integer so no need to "iterate" over it, just simply add it to your result set.

```
for {
  n <- strand
} yield (n, count(n))
```

On a side note this solution is not too optimal as in the case of a strand `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` count is going to be called many times. I would recommend calling `toSet` so you get the distinct `Char`s only:

```
for {
  n <- strand.toSet
} yield (n, count(n))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I knew it was something simple.  Scala is a weird language to wrap your head around at first, but that makes sense.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: In regards to your edit with setting it equal .toSet, I am getting this error now:

Error:(9, 7) missing parameter type
      n <- strand.toSet
      ^

Why is it asking for a parameter with that suggestion?

Comment: Hm, it should be able to figure out that this is a set of `Char`, you can try explicitly typing it: `.toSet[Char]`

Comment: I explicitly stated n:Char which fixed it, just was curious as to why it wasn't figuring out the type as you mentioned.  Your fix also works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In line with Akos's approach, consider a parallel traversal of a given strand (`String`),

```
strand.distinct.par.map( n => n -> count(n) )
```

Here we use distinct to gather unique items and construct each `Map` association in `map`.

Comment: Nice!  I like this succinct solution.  Why would a parallel solution be more optimal in this case?  I don't implement a lot of parallelism in what I do, so curious as to how the .par command works on a String object call.  Thanks!

Comment: @Imcphers Scala string is equipped with ordered collections methods so a string resorts to such collections methods. With par we obtain a parallel version of a collection, thereafter we can apply heavy computations on each item in the collection in parallel. Here this may prove of interest for very large counting, although a very large collection is needed. Many Thanks for enquiring on this :)

Comment: No worries, thanks for giving such an insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline solution would look like:

```
def nucleotideCounts() = strand.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```

Comment: No, `n` will be each `Char` in the string. Try it out for yourself: `for { n <- "abc" } { println(n) }`

Comment: `for { n <- "abc" } yield { n.toInt }` results in: `Vector(97, 98, 99)` So the elements are separate and not "initially set to the whole strand String" as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is

`Map() ++ {for (n <- strand; c = count(n)) yield n->c}`

Not sure why it's different than {...}.toMap() but it gets the job done!

Another way to go is

`Map() ++ {for (n <- strand; c <- Seq(count(n))) yield n->c}`

Comment: If you are "Not sure why ...", don't answer and don't misguide the others.